# Compare certain lines in text files

Tags: php, count, text-files, nested-loops

Im trying to compare the first 10 lines of 100 lines of $completeGoogle(5000Lines) and count the number of matches with another file. However my count should be between 1-10 and I am getting an answer of 5010???

```
foreach(new SplFileObject($completeGoogle) as $n => $line)
             if($n % 100 < 10)
                {
                    $f_Api = fopen($apiFile,'r');

                for ($i = 0 ;$i < 10; $i++)
                    {
                    $top10 = fgets($f_Api);
                        if ($line === $top10);
                            {
                            $count++;
                            }
                    }

                    fclose($f_Api);
                }
```

Comment: You never increment `$n`

Comment: $n is in a foreach loop, it increments each time.

Comment: @Summoner good call; I didn't see that there.

Comment: You are checking if the remainder of dividing by 100 is less than 10. So, you're `if` is not doing what you think it does.

Comment: Why not just have a counter that causes your foreach to break once it hits 100 instead of $n % 100?

Comment: I don't quite understand what he means by "the first 10 lines of 100 lines of $completeGoogle(5000Lines)", but judging by the code Matt is probably right.

Comment: thats to read every 10 lines so line 1->10, line 101->110 line 201->210 etc.

Comment: Well assuming $n starts at 0, then yes.

Comment: Put a count variable inside the `foreach` outside of the `if` and let us know how many times that loop is executing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You compare each 1-9, 100-109... line in one file with 10 lines from another and sum all matches in one variable `$count`.
If everything is equal you must get 500 (lines from first file) * 10 (lines from other) = 5000 matches.

Comment: The problem is the matches are not equal.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this was failing my was because of a simple ";" after the if statement.

```
foreach(new SplFileObject($completeGoogle) as $n => $line)
             if($n % 100 < 10)
                {
                    $f_Api = fopen($apiFile,'r');

                for ($i = 0 ;$i < 10; $i++)
                    {
                    $top10 = fgets($f_Api);
                        if ($line === $top10)
                            {
                            $count++;
                            }
                    }

                    fclose($f_Api);
                }
```